# Actions in Ember 2.5--route or controller?

Tags: ember.js

I've been anticipating the end of controllers when routable components are coming in the future. So I've been putting my action handlers in my routes.

```
// app/something/route.js
actions: {
    doSomething() {
         alert('action handled in route');
    }
}
```

In my template:

```
{{!-- app/something/template.hbs --}}
{{some-component action="doSomething"}}
```

In my component:

```
{{!-- app/components/some-component/template.hbs --}}
<button {{action "onClickButton"}}>Click Me</button>

// app/components/some-component/component.js
actions: {
    onClickButton() {
       this.sendAction();
    }
}
```

Should I be handling actions in the route and avoiding controllers completely?

Comment: No, you should not be avoiding controllers. That's counter-productive and unnecessary.

Comment: Fine, but I see advice to the contrary  http://emberigniter.com/should-we-use-controllers-ember-2.0/ but not a lot of direction. Care to point me to some documentation that I'm missing?

Comment: https://locks.svbtle.com/controllers-are-dead-long-life-controllers https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/controllers/

Comment: Thanks locks--your blog post predates the guides that still said controllers were going away [link](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/controllers/). "Controllers are very much like components, so much so that in future versions of Ember, controllers will be replaced entirely with components.". However, I noticed [this git commit](https://github.com/emberjs/guides/commit/94e8167e04403b81e4837d587a119089ff8007bc#diff-af7a62ebe5526bfdb34a776bb508b879) last month by trek changed the wording to sound like controllers are not going away. So I think my confusion is understandable.

Comment: That was an unfortunate messaging slip-up. You can reach me in the Ember.js Slack and I'll talk your ear off about the details ;)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! And thanks for your work on the Ember Learning team.

Comment: https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper !

According to that git commit it seems like the core team has changed its stance? Honestly there would be much less confusion in an Ember without controllers. I understand things take time, but it seems that all this defence of controllers is simply because routable components are not ready. It don't see any other compelling reason.

Comment: @emberigniter you didn't link to a specific commit. You can find me on the usual places to discuss this more appropriately.

Comment: @locks Would be happy to talk about this! What's an appropriate place to discuss, Slack? I did not, but Paul Oliver did link to a specific commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that controllers are *not* going away, thanks to input from [@locks](https://github.com/locks) on the Ember Learning Team.

According to [his blog post](https://locks.svbtle.com/controllers-are-dead-long-life-controllers):

> Being future-proof does not mean never using any controller ever.

and

> Generate controllers for all your routes.

You can even see in this [git commit](https://github.com/emberjs/guides/commit/94e8167e04403b81e4837d587a119089ff8007bc#diff-af7a62ebe5526bfdb34a776bb508b879) from `trek` that the Ember team is softening their stance on controllers.

So, in closing, controllers are fine to use. That's where I'm putting my actions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really great package I have been using to solve this temporarily:

https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper

A full write up on the rationale is here (https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/02/19/best-practices-route-actions), with the key point being:

`"This addon gives you all the goodness of closure actions, and is a great way of taking steps to future proof your Ember application. When Routable Components do land, and actions work correctly, then upgrading your app simply becomes a search and replace for s/route-action/action."`

Comment: Nice find Sam! I'm definitely checking this out.